# Op-amp rail-to-rail voltage follower latching up

Tags: operational-amplifier

I have selected a TS922 op-amp to use in a voltage follower configuration. The specs for the TS922 in summary are:

- Rail-to-rail input and output
- Low noise: 9 nV/√Hz
- Low distortion
- High output current: 80 mA (able to drive 32 Ω loads)
- High-speed: 4 MHz, 1 V/μs
- Operating from 2.7 to 12 V
- Low input offset voltage: 900 μV max.
- Latch-up immunity

The voltage follower configuration is:

[image: voltage follower]

Supply voltage is 5 V.

To test I am using a simple 10 kΩ pot arrangement (range supply voltage to GND) to apply a voltage to the input (pin 3) with a voltmeter measuring the output on pin 1.

My issue is that the TS922 output latches up to 4.7 V if the input voltage rises above 3.6 V. If the input voltage is less than 3.6 V the TS922 behaves as a voltage follower.

To try to identify why this is happening I have tried:

- placing a light load (2 kΩ resistor) from pin 1 to ground - no effect
- grounding the inputs to the other dual amp in case there was some interaction - no effect.

Is there something I am missing? Otherwise I suspect the markings on this device don't match what is inside.

I would also appreciate any advice on other op-amps which are close to the TS922. The most important specs are:

- single supply 5 V.
- rail to rail input/output.
- high output current capability > 50 mA.

I know I can search for devices, but I am hoping someone has experience with a device that works well.

Comment: This happens no matter which amp you use? You said there are two on the chip.

Comment: Where did you get the part?  I've seen parts from brokers do odd things.

Comment: Yes I have tried both amps and have tried the other chips in the batch of 5 I bought.

Comment: The \$3.6\:\text{V}\$ tells me that your pot is split into \$2.8\:\text{k}\Omega\$ and \$7.2\:\text{k}\Omega\$ when things go awry. (The source impedance is then about \$2\:\text{k}\Omega\$.) The datasheet says that the maximum input current *must not exceed* \$1\:\text{mA}\$ for either input and cannot be allowed to be \$\pm 1\:\text{V}\$ apart. I'm wondering about a flaky pot that "jitters." Can you replace the pot and use two resistors as a divider that presents a higher voltage? Perhaps \$2.7\:\text{k}\Omega\$ and \$7.5\:\text{k}\Omega\$? Just to eliminate this idea?

Comment: In a voltage follower configuration the differential voltage can not exceed +/- 1 volt The TS922 spec says " The differential voltage is the non-inverting input terminal with respect to the inverting input terminal. If Vid  > ±1 V, the maximum input current must not exceed ±1 mA. In this case (Vid > ±1 V), an input series resistor must be added to limit the input current. " So I don't  see the 1ma limit as a problem. BUT I will test with a higher impedance input.

Comment: I have tested with a higher impedance input (100k pot) and lower (5k pot)  - the latch up still happens at around 3.6v.  Of course this has also eliminated the possibility of a "jittery" pot. Maybe someone has a TS922 they could try??

Comment: Did you test with DC input or a pulse?  Put 5K on the feedback path and input path to limit both input currents to 1mA on Vdd=5V on a step pulse.  Then test with DC input , sine triangle square with/without loads but with decoupling cap.

Comment: Looks to me like you're doing everything correctly. The amplifier's common mode input voltage range extends _beyond_ the supply range so you're good there. It's a follower so the differential input voltage is essentially zero. It's fully specified for 5V operation. You might have counterfeit parts. Might I ask where the parts were purchased?

Comment: The TSS922 were bought on aliexpress from a supplier in Shenzen. Device marking is TS922IN  90B1432 with the ST Microelectronic logo and MAL (I presume Malaysia)

Comment: I have also tested with a sine wave input. Output on the scope shows latch up on the > 3.6v peaks.

Comment: @IanF most probably the part is counterfeit, AliExpress is well-known for such surprises.

Comment: AliExpress is a worse source for bad/counterfeit parts than local markets and sellers domestically within China because there are unscrupulous sellers who know it's very expensive to return parts with tracking. Caveat emptor.

Answer (score 3):

A couple of days ago I tested some op amps in voltage follower configurations.
All op-amps were bought from a reputable vendor (TME).

[image]

The input signal was coming from the function generator, \$F = 1\textrm{kHz}\$ and the signal amplitude was \$10\mathrm{ V}\$ peak to peak.

And all op amps were also supplied from symmetrical supply \$+/-5\mathrm{ V}\$.

Hence we can easily examine the allowed input common mode voltage range.

The first one was \$\textrm{LM}358\$ from ST.

[image]

As you can clipping accrue for \$V_\mathrm{in} > (V_\mathrm{cc}-1.4\mathrm{ V})\$

And no sign of a famous crossover distortion due to lack of load resistance.

But reducing the input signal amplitude and adding a load resistance reveals the crossover distortion.

[image]

The second op amp was \$\textrm{TS922}\$ from ST

[image]

As you can see \$V_\mathrm{in} = V_\mathrm{out}\$ as expected from a rail-to-rail input and output op amp.

No sign of "latching-up".

Hence, if your setup is correct I vote for a counterfeit part from China. Not a big surprise either.

Next one was \$\textrm{TL}072\$ from TI.

[image]

As you can see we got a clipping for \$V_\mathrm{in} > (V_\mathrm{cc}-0.6\mathrm{ V})\$ or so.
And when the input signal approaches \$V_\mathrm{EE} - 1.4\mathrm{ V}\$ phase inversion phenomenon manifests itself.

And finally the \$\textrm{NE}5532\$ from Philips.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the helpful info.  Have you tested any of these devices with a single supply?  For example the TS922 is optimised for 3 and 5 volts.

Comment: To be clear, if you consider Vee as -5V, then I think it should be Vee+1.4 Volts instead of Vee-1.4 volts, anyway thank you for answer, it was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Place a .1uF ceramic capacitor between Power and Ground and add resistors in series with both inputs to the op amp. The 2KOhm you added to the output would work.

Answer (score 0):

You bought an electronic IC from a seller in China. Of course it is counterfeit.
Here is what Wikipedia says about AliExpress in Google:[image: AliExpress]

Comment: Really, that's the first result you get for searching "AliExpress"? Sounds like fake news. That said, the source of the parts means there is a *non-negligible* chance they are counterfeit. I doubt it's 100%.

Comment: I have purchased a wide variety of electronic components via Aliexpress over several years. My experience had actually been good up to this particular part. In this case I contacted Aliexpress and they have refunded with no problem.

Comment: The Wikipedia link above does not give the result as shown.

Answer (score -1):

Must be a counterfeit part - there is no other explanation.

Comment: The device is definitely counterfeit. I tested TS922 devices from a reputable supplier and they work as expected in the same test setup - no latch up.  Thanks all.