# Opamp input offset voltage...common mode?

Tags: operational-amplifier, common-mode, input-offset-voltage

Looking at the [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/general/docs/suppproductinfo.tsp?distId=26&gotoUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ti.com%2Flit%2Fds%2Fsymlink%2Fopa197-q1.pdf) for an OPA197 opamp, I see this:

[image: Datasheet snippet]

What is the circled expression trying to tell me?

The common mode voltage is equal to the voltage at the non-inverting input minus 1.5 V which is equal to plus or minus 10 µV?  I can't follow that.

Where does the 1.5 V come from?  What is the point of this section in the datasheet?

Comment: \$ (V+) \$ refers to the DC supply voltage, not the non-inverting input pin.

Comment: Try read this https://e2e.ti.com/blogs_/archives/b/thesignal/archive/2012/05/08/op-amp-voltage-ranges-input-and-output-clearing-some-confusion  and here you can find what can happen when you ignore CM range https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/432775/op-amp-rail-to-rail-voltage-follower-latching-up/432924#432924

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The circled expression is under the "Test Conditions" heading so it is describing the conditions under which the input offset voltage was measured.

V+ is the name of the positive power supply pin:

[image: OPA197 pinout]

The non-inverting and inverting inputs are called +IN A/B and -IN A/B, respectively.

The expression is therefore telling you that the input offset voltage was measured with a common mode voltage set to 1.5V below the V+ voltage. This information is necessary because the top of the table (which you can see in your screenshot) says that

> \$V_{\text{CM}} = V_{\text{OUT}} = V_{\text{S}} / 2\$ ... (unless otherwise noted)

Without this note you would assume the common mode voltage was \$V_{\text{S}} / 2\$ when the input offset voltage was measured. *That* measurement is given in the first three lines of the input offset voltage specification (where each of those lines is for different temperatures).

Comment: This answers my question very nicely, thank you.  I will wait a bit before accepting to give others a chance.

Comment: @evildemonic Happy to help.

Answer (score 5):

To add a little continuation to @Null 's answer. It also talks about the voltage range in section 7.3.6 of this datasheet.

[image]

and also it tells you the modes of operation with these transistors on the next page...

[image]

Comment: +1 Note to OP, the PFET diff pair is trimed in final test, the NFET diff pair is not. This is visible in Fig 11 in the datasheet

Answer (score 0):

If you operate the opamp in non-inverting gain circuit, that  50 microvolt bump may be a bad thing for your signal processing.