# Is exceeding Opamp Common Mode Voltage safe?

Tags: operational-amplifier, common-mode, reliability, overheat, rail-to-rail

I understand that when you exceed an Opamps Common mode voltage limit that the output will no longer be reliable. And that this limit is often a bit less that the supply rails. But would slightly exceeding this limit to perhaps the supply rail cause the Opamp to blow up or overheat? Or would it just cause the output to be inaccurate?

Comment: Read the data sheet because there is no general answer.

Comment: If the common-mode voltage does not exceed the supply rails voltage nothing will blow.  https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/432775/op-amp-rail-to-rail-voltage-follower-latching-up/432924#432924

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few op-amps allow the supply rails to be exceeded without damage. Many require the inputs to remain within the supply rails (or no more than a few hundred mV outside, or current limited). It really depends on the op-amp. Read the abs. max ratings for what might damage the op-amp even if momentarily exceeded. Read the recommended ratings for what to do in normal operation. Note that the ratings apply even when no supply voltage is applied.

For example, with the ubiquitous LM358/LM324 op-amp you can exceed the positive rail (up to 32V) but going more than a few hundred mV below the negative rail can destroy the chip. Most CMOS op-amps eg. TLC27L2 do not allow either supply rail to be exceeded by more than a few hundred mV. Sometimes 0mV is specified.

If you exceed the common mode range, you cannot expect the op-amp to behave properly (though it might in some cases). As you noted in some cases the output will go to the opposite rail than expected, which can cause some poorly-designed circuits to latch up. Also note that you should use "worst case" common mode range, which means not just using the worst case figures on the datasheet, but also allowing for temperature if that is not accounted for. For example, the [LM324](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm324-n.pdf) has a common mode range that includes 0V to V+ -1.5V worst case, but only at 25°C. The manufacturer has not seen fit to grace us with even typical characteristics of Vcm with temperature, but a quick glance at the schematic would tend to indicate that low temperatures will be worse, by at least 4mV/°C, so one might allow V+ -2V (and verify at least typical characteristics in a test chamber if low temperature operation is required).

Answer (score 3):

"Safe" in my view means: no person gets hurt

Do persons get hurt if you exceed the Maximum ratings of an opamp? I have yet to see that happen so my answer would be: **Yes, it is safe.**

But you might actually be asking **if the opamp can get damaged**, right?

Well, that's simple. Look in the datasheet. If you exceed the **Maximum ratings** then you risk damaging the opamp.

If you don't exceed the Maximum ratings then no damage should happen.

There is no point in asking what will happen, what the damage (if any) there will be as that depends on so many circumstances and will be different for every model of opamp. So there is no general answer to what the damage will cause as it depends. And the answer is irrelevant as you simply should **not** be using an opamp outside its maximum ratings.

Answer (score 3):

There are two considerations in the data sheet.

The first is in the electrical specification section.  If you keep to the specs in this section, the chip will perform as predicted.

The the next is in the Absolute Maximum section.  If you leave the bounds listed in the electrical spec, bu you don't leave the bounds outlined in the Absolute Maximum section, the IC is pretty much guaranteed to keep functioning to spec once you return to the parameter bounds listed in the electrical spec.  If you leave the bounds of the Absolute Maximum section, the IC is no longer guaranteed to perform to spec ever again.

Answer (score 1):

Exceeding the common-mode voltage range causes no damage.
Some opamps even reverse the polarity of the output if the common-mode voltage range is exceeded causing severe distortion.

[image: Image showing phase inversion]

<sub>Image source: [Analog Devices - Application Note AN-849 - Using Op Amps as Comparators](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/application-notes/AN-849.pdf)</sub>